# 5 stages of grief in An Inspector Calls

Tags: interpretation, an-inspector-calls, j-b-priestley

Would it make sense if inspector Goole was a relative of Eva and we are in his mind as he goes through the five stages of grief? This does not mean that he goes through these five stages in order but that the following characters represent such stages:

- Sheila: acceptance,
- Eric: depression,
- Mr Birling: denial,
- Mrs Birling: anger,
- Gerald: bargaining.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community The question asks whether the play can be *interpreted* this way. There is no requirement for interpretations to be obvious.

Answer (score 2):

The Five Stages of Grief are a sequence of emotions identified in the 1969 book On Death and Dying by Elisabeth Kübler-Ross.

The first problem with your proposition is that it does not, by your own assessment, follow the sequence.

Kübler-Ross described this set of emotions as being experienced sequentially by *patients* on learning that *their own illness is terminal*.

The second problem with your proposition is that the sequence was not conceived in application to those bereaved when others die. It was conceived as experienced by the *dying*, not be the bereaved.

Also notice the date, 1969 is 24 years *after* the first performance of An Inspector Calls in 1945.

So the third problem for the proposition is that it preceded the identification of the stages by almost a quarter century.

For the play to demonstrate a progression through *the five stages of grief* you would have to show that Kübler-Ross was only the first to codify some general cultural knowledge about the stages of grief,  perhaps changing the *sequence* in order to apply them to people receiving news of their own impending death rather than those who are experiencing bereavement.

Comment: "So the third problem for the proposition is that it preceded the identification of the stages by almost a quarter century." Can you please explain how this is a problem? We have Marxist criticism of Romantic poetry, psychoanalytic criticism of Shakespeare, feminist criticism of the Bible, etcetera. So why would *On Death and Dying* being published after *An Inspector Calls* be an issue if Marx's work being more recent than Romanticism clearly isn't?

Comment: @Tsundoku I really don't understand your question. I've included in the answer that for the play to be demonstrating that progression through grief before the 5SoG were identified would require that the 5SoG were generally recognised prior to K-R publishing on the topic. K-R was publishing on the topic of terminally ill people coming to terms with their diagnoses, not on *An Inspector Calls*. I see I may have been less specific in my final paragraph than I intended, so I'll amend that. Otherwise I'm at a loss as to your meaning,

Comment: The point of my comment is that there is no requirement for the five stages of grief to be published before *An Inspector Calls* (unless you assume authorial intent, which the question does not). Similarly, psychoanalysis is much more recent than many of the works that are interpreted using psychoanalytic criticism.